# fetching mysql data PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new to PDO i'm trying to get data from my mysql table I've looked around the web and other stackoverflow answers but they all seem to have additional code added that just gets me confused.

I want to just echo out all the data from one of my tables I got this far:

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, location, age FROM students");
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "students");
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Connection info

```
function getConnection()
{
    $DCONFIG_server = "localhost";
    $DCONFIG_DBuser = "root";
    $DCONFIG_DBpass = "root";
    $DCONFIG_dbname = "school";

    $conn = null;

    try
    {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$DCONFIG_server;dbname=$DCONFIG_dbname",$DCONFIG_DBuser, $DCONFIG_DBpass );
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $conn;
}
```

Comment: does your output contain the data you expect to retrieve from your db table? `name`, `location` and `age`?

Comment: I of course have a dbconnect file that I include

Comment: I get no output from the above code

Comment: what's the result if you `var_dump($sth->execute())`? So you can proceed by step

Comment: Did you define `class students`? Did you enable PDO to throw exceptions, or else if you didn't do that, did you check the return values from prepare() and execute() for **false** which would indicate an error?

Comment: Also `FETCH_CLASS` seems to be a `fetch_argument` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)
Maybe you need a fetch_style before, as first parameter

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a class students?

```
<?php
    class students {
        public $name;
        public $location;
        public $age;
    }
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, location, age FROM students");
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "students");
var_dump($result);
?>
```